# How to "close" database when the query happens?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$database->count = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE item_id = 1"

if($database->count == 1)
{
   $database->update = "UPDATE users SET money = money - 1000";
   $database->delete = "DELETE table WHERE item_id = 1";
}
```

Let's say I have this code (I've just created it) in index.php page. Can at the same time `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE item_id = 1"` query happen so two people would get count 1 and -1000 money? If yes, how can I avoid that?

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for thinking about [Race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're worried about two queries running at the same time being responsible for unbalanced state in your DB, you should be using transactions : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Transactions are helpful in keeping the state of your data correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can `LOCK TABLE table WRITE` before and `UNLOCK TABLE table` after the queries.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Any technique - transactions, locking, waiting a second and requerying - to prevent race conditions has a chance of making the page slower (but if your queries are speedy, the slowdown is generally minimal). It's up to you whether that's worth it - if you're dealing with money amounts, it's probably better for the page to take an extra second to load than to tell someone they have a thousand dollars more than they actually do.

Comment: Locking the table is only required for MyISAM tables, to do "fake" transactions. InnoDB has row-level locking and doesn't require table-level locks.

Comment: @Marc B: so if I have InnoDB, than I am ok and don't need to worry?

Comment: You still need to use transactions and row-level locks to make sure no other query stomps on the updates you're doing. But yeah, don't worry about table locks for this sort of thing. table-level innodb locks are for 'big picture' things, like dumping the database during backups.

Answer (score 1):

You need [transactions](http://www.linuxdig.com/news_page/1079394922.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InnoDB, you can play with the Transaction Isolation Level so that dirty reads are not allowed. Make sure you use repeatable reads as your Transaction Isolation Level.

BTW The DELETE line should say DELETE FROM table WHERE item_id = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the databases have transaction support so If you are using mysql as you are working with PHP so you will need table locking technique.
Your table will be locked unless all work will be done than you unlock it, you can specify row locking as well.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Best :) Waqar Alamgir

Comment: Transaction support has nothing to do with PHP, it's all about the MySQL database engine being used.

Comment: Mostly php applications running mysql server

Comment: It's pretty trivial to switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: @ceejayoz I did'nt saw your anser, sorry btw